private-gpt timed out when running it inside a container as opposed to non-dockerized on the same host
I'm trying to dockerize private-gpt (https://docs.privategpt.dev/overview/welcome/introduction).
I've been successfully able to run it locally and it works just fine on my MacBook M1.
I've been also able to dockerize it and run it inside a container as a pre-step for my next steps (deploying on different hosts), but this time when trying to get a response it hangs and finally timed-out:
private-gpt-1  | 11:51:39.191 [WARNING ] llama_index.core.chat_engine.types - Encountered exception writing response to history: timed out

I did increase docker resources such as CPU/memory/Swap up to the maximum level, but sadly it didn't solve the issue.
Any idea how can I overcome this?
